# Swirling Dust Clouds in Caverns

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation

Are the chances to recover items from the dust swirls the same for all the items(particularly the type gems)?

And does the chances of what you receive/encounter from the dust depend on the cavern the dust is found in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the information provided on [one area on Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Chargestone_Cave), the item found does not vary between areas, however the pokemon does (excadrill is only in later areas) . There is no information so far on item frequency.